# need help with bibliography, to replace comma with colon after volume

Tags: biblatex

i need a little help with my bibliography. This is my code (Im new to this):

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
natbib=true,
sorting=nyvt,
]{biblatex}
\linespread{1.25}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook]{title}{#1}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page             ={},
  pages            ={},
} 

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\bibstring{in}%
     \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}


\addbibresource{bibliography/references.bib}
```

and it creates this output:
Wright A. -D. G. and D. H. Lynn. 1997. Maximum ages of ciliate lineages estimated
using a small subunit rRNA molecular clock: crown eukaryotes date back to the
Paleoproterozoic. Archiv für Protistenkunde 148, 329–341.
44

**What i need is to remove the comma after volume and replace it with colon** to look like this:
Archiv für Protistenkunde 148: 329–341.

Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

What you are referring to is the command `\bibpagespunct`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibpagespunct.bib}
@article{aksin,
    author       = {Aks{\i}n, {\"O}zge and T{\"u}rkmen, Hayati and Artok, Levent
        and {\c{C}}etinkaya, Bekir and Ni, Chaoying and
        B{\"u}y{\"u}kg{\"u}ng{\"o}r, Orhan and {\"O}zkal, Erhan},
    title        = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of
        saturated {Pd-N}-heterocyclic carbenes in {Mizoroki-Heck}
        reactions},
    journaltitle = jomch,
    date         = 2006,
    volume       = 691,
    pages        = {3027-3036},
    indextitle   = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
natbib=true,
sorting=nyvt,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibpagespunct.bib} 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    page  ={},
    pages ={},
}

\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\color{IndianRed1}:}

\begin{document} 
    
    Basmah
    
    \cite{aksin}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```